# How to use various calculations for various inputs

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing a program that will let the user enter various types of information to calculate the expenses for a vacation trip.

I am given the costs of three different forms of transportation, as well as four source cities and four destination cities.

The three forms of travel are air, train and bus, while the source cities are Baltimore, Chattanooga, Nashville, and Pasadena. The destination cities are Denver, Madison, Clarksville, and Knoxville.

I need to be able to calculate the cost to travel between each source and each destination city depending on what the user enters (form of travel, and each city).

Now, my first guess was to write a very very long if/else if statement for each condition. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work either because it is so long or maybe I messed up somewhere.

```
if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 5000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 4000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 5000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 2500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 2500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 2500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 800;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 1000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 2500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 4000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 4000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 6000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 2300;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 1600;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 600;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 1300;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 1400;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'C', 'c' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 1700;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 5000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 2500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 4000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 4500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 1500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 900;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 1500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 1700;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 1400;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 700;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 1000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'N', 'n' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 1300;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 5000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 4500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 3000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 4500;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 2000;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 1900;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 1200;

    else if(transportation_type == 'T', 't' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'C', 'c')
        transportation_price = 1700;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
        transportation_price = 1400;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'M', 'm')
        transportation_price = 1300;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'K', 'k')
        transportation_price = 800;

    else if(transportation_type == 'B', 'b' && src_city == 'P', 'p' && dest_city == 'C', 'c');
        transportation_price = 1300;
```

I use chars to symbolize each city and form of transportation. This if/else if statement does not work, as in my output all it gives me is a value of $1300 despite what the user enters.

Is there any way I can shorten this down? Or if I messed up somewhere can someone point it out for me?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show a [mre]. You should also learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem: Follow code does not compare `transportation_type` to `'A'` and
`transportation_type` to `'a'`. <sup>1</sup>

```
transportation_type == 'A', 'a'  // bad
```

Instead fold the case.

```
// transportation_type == 'A', 'a'
toupper((unsigned char)transportation_type) == 'A'
```

Same for others.

---

Suggest a one time change before the `if()`.

```
#include <ctype.h>

transportation_type = toupper((unsigned char) transportation_type);
src_city = toupper((unsigned char) src_city);
dest_city = toupper((unsigned char) dest_city);

// if(transportation_type == 'A', 'a' && src_city == 'B', 'b' && dest_city == 'D', 'd')
if(transportation_type == 'A' && src_city == 'B' && dest_city == 'D')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `transportation_type == 'A', 'a'` uses the comma operator. The result is `'a'`.  The result of the compare is lost.

Comma operator with `&&` further complicates things.  IAC, `,` is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, use only uppercase selections or convert the selections to the same case. Additionally, you can store the trip combinations in an array to make the code the cleaner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    char transportation_type = 'A';
    char src_city = 'B';
    char dest_city = 'K';
    int transportation_price = 0;
          
    if(transportation_type == 'A' && src_city == 'B' && dest_city == 'D')
            transportation_price = 5000;
            
    else if(transportation_type == 'A' && src_city == 'B' && dest_city == 'M')
            transportation_price = 4000;
    
    else if(transportation_type == 'A' && src_city == 'B' && dest_city == 'K')
            transportation_price = 5000;
    
    printf("%i\n",transportation_price);
    
    
    // better way, store trip combinations in array
    
    char trips[4][3] = {
        {'A','B','D'},
        {'A','B','M'},
        {'A','B','K'},
        {'A','B','C'}
    };
    
    int cost[4] = {
        5000,4000,5000,2500
    };
    
    for (int t=0; t<3; t++) {
        if(transportation_type == trips[t][0] && src_city == trips[t][1] && dest_city == trips[t][2]) {
              transportation_price = cost[t];
              break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%i\n",transportation_price);
    
    return transportation_price;
}
```

Output

```
5000
5000
```